# Switching from working node js socket io serialport to node express router how to?

Tags: express, sockets, io

I am new to node express (started with node long time ago but didn't do much) and I would like to learn how to use it. I am going through some of my older work and reading lots of tutorials but I just can't seem to get this one working.
I have this app that reads data from some sensors on serial port and sends it to sesors.ejs. I would like to reprogram it in express. I have the sensor reading in terminal but not in ejs.

old (working) app.js

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var url = require('url');
var path = require('path');

const { SerialPort } = require('serialport')
const { ByteLengthParser } = require('@serialport/parser-byte-length')
const port = new SerialPort({ path: 'COM4', baudRate: 9600 })
const parser = port.pipe(new ByteLengthParser({ length: 30 }))

var sensors = fs.readFileSync('views/sensors.ejs');

var app = http.createServer(function(req, res){
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
res.end(sensors);
});

var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
io.on('connection', function(data){
console.log
});

parser.on('data', function(data){
console.log(data.toString("UTF8"));
io.emit('data', data.toString("UTF8"))
});

app.listen(3000);
```

old (working) sensors.ejs

```
<script>    
var socket = io();
socket.on('data', function(data){...} 
</script>
```

This works great.

I went through several express routing tutorials but **I don't know how to send io data to router**.

I have c/p most of the code from old app.js to new sensor.js in routes dir, without fs, app.listen etc. I have c/p sensors.ejs to views folder.

In new app.js I have:

```
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var sensorsRouter = require('./routes/senzori');

var app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(\__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(\__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/senzori', sensorsRouter);
```

index.ejs and users.ejs (fetch mysql data) are working (express is installed and working)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. If anyone else with my level of "knowledge" needs the solution, here it is:

I have moved reading serial port to bin/www

The only code in sensors.js is:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('sensors');
});
```